# I Can't Access System Tray Icons in GNOME

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, lts, system-tray

I am using Ubuntu Unity on the most current lts edition. I installed the GNOME desktop session and am currently using it. I have a problem with my GNOME setup however. I use OBS Studio for screencasting but I always have it set to hide to my system tray so that it doesn't show up in the recording. When I installed Obs today I used that same feature and now I cannot access it because I have no system tray. Is there a way to access the system tray icons from somewhere like a dropdown menu on the top menu or does GNOME just have no system tray?

Comment: GNOME has something called "legacy tray" at the bottom left corner: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-3B8FIL0yQuE/VRK-UYi0lvI/AAAAAAAAV68/br2MBn3KmC0/s1600/gnome316-tray-icons.png

Comment: I can't find it. Do I need to install it? I also have dash to dock installed. Does that change anything?

Comment: It should be appearing by default. I don't think Dash to dock conflicts with legacy tray. Try this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/
This extension moves legacy tray icons to panel.

Comment: This still doesn't add the icon tray or even any icons at all. I still only have my clock and logout/battery options at the top. ;(

Comment: Try reinstalling gnome-shell

Comment: Is the tray icon in the form of an extension because I had no extensions installed when I first installed GNOME yesterday.

Comment: No, legacy tray is a part of the shell, not an extension. It contains running applications that use notification icons, for example Dropbox, Thunderbird, Skype, KeepassX etc.

Comment: I just reinstalled GNOME shell and the Legacy Tray is still not visible and the Topicons Plus extension isn't working for Obs either. I don't understand why this is as I installed Ubuntu a couple days ago and installed GNOME alongside Unity as I love both but can't spare more hard drive space with my KDE Manjaro duel-boot. I haven't changed any permissions or ownerships of files on my hard drive and I've only installed a couple theme packs and Blender and Obs.